# How do I put ArsClip to start on windows boot?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I used to put it on the Startup folder but since I upgraded to Windows 8, now if I put the .exe over on that folder it opens 5 file explorer windows and 5 notepad files on system bootup. I also notice there's no more option during installation to start the program on system bootup and it gives me this message about it not functioning properly on Win Vista and higher, although I've never had a problem with ArsClip on Win 7. Anyone knows any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the Startup folder directly, not through the shortcut path;

Windows Key + R
Type %appdata& and press enter
Navigate to "\Microsoft\WIndows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

You can try that. Let me know if it works.

Comment: That's what I usually did, now it places a bunch of folders over at the the startup folder automatically (like iconcache, textcache and other cache) and opens up these files and windows that I mentioned previously.

Comment: In msconfig, does it show the program listed in the "startup" tab?

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: Try making a different program running on startup by using the same method. This would negate an issue with the OS and be specific to the application

Comment: I have an AHK script and LastPass running just fine by that method. I guess it should be program specific